# What is this? Looks like a sensor

Tags: sensors

I got an Arduino kit from my dad. 
But inside this box is a thing, maybe a sensor. But I can't find what it is.
Anyone recognize this 'thing' on the picture?

[image]

Comment: What is written on the chip? Is there anything printed on the reverse of the board?

Comment: No it's just a black surface. also the backside is blank.

Comment: I can see the ghost of some lettering on the chip. Look closely. You may need a magnifying glass (or even microscope) and some spit to make it visible.

Comment: My guess is that it’s a touch sensor. Where you have to touch the white circle. But the number of components on the board makes me doubt that guess.

Comment: @Gerben That was my first thought, and main concern, too. Hence wanting to try and find a chip number. Chances are it's just a generic op-amp on there though.

Comment: Have you tried hooking it to a 5V supply and connecting it to a Arduino/buzzer?  Then just wave various other items from the kit at it.  But it would be easier to read the writing on the IC, zoom on you phone might work.

Comment: To read letters on chips it is good just draw over the chip with chalk (or any other fine powder (be it sugar, baby powder, lady powder...), then decently blow out what is on top and the letters wiil be left powder-filed and readable. Then you can simply remove the rest of powder totally if you wish (with finger, or nearly anything damp/wet). Good trick to know :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Appears to be a touch sensor that can be found on various on-line retail web pages:

[http://www.satistronics.com/](http://www.satistronics.com/k1208043-diy-touch-sensor-switch-module-for-arduino-works-with-official-arduino-boards_p4096.html)

[https://www.arduiner.com/](https://www.arduiner.com/en/tilt-touch-vibration/85-touch-sensor-touch-switch-module-smart-car-arduino-3809200620547.html)

Also, the back may have a URL as this one does:

[image]

...however, the URL appears not to function.

Comment: The back has no text, but it looks  the same. I followed your link and it shows exactly what I have. Thank you for sharing this with me

Comment: The sensor is a K1208043 touch sensor. Here's an updated [link](http://www.satistronics.com/k1208043-diy-touch-sensor-switch-module-for-arduino-works-with-official-arduino-boards_p4096.html).